# To const or not to const--What to declare when my code won't modify user code's string but third-party code I depend on forgot to declare const?

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing, constants

Think of the following code as a large project developed in an organization, where `our_function()` is developed in-house and we have all control over it. `main()` is written by our users who would link to our library and invoke `our_function()`. But `third_party_function()` was developed by another external company and we have no control over it; we can only use it as is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void third_party_function(char *s)
{
  // s[1] = 'E'; // We're sure that this function doesn't have code like this.
  printf("third_party_function: s: %s\n", s);
}

void our_function(const char *s)
{
  /* Do something with s but treat it as read-only. */

  /* our_function depends on third_party_function. we know that
   * third_party_function is never supposed to modify the string passed to it
   * but the third party developer of third_party_function forgot to declare
   * its argument as 'const char *', hence the type cast below. */
  third_party_function((char *) s);
}

int main()
{
  char *s = "hello, world";

  /* Do something with s, but treat it as read-only. */

  /* our_function is developed in-house; we are sure that our_function should
   * never modify the string passed to it. */
  our_function("hello, world");

  /* Do something more with s. Here we just print it to make sure
   * our_function() has not modified it. */
  printf("main: s: %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

We are 100% sure that `our_function()` would never modify the string passed to it.

We are also 100% sure that `third_party_function()` would never modify the string passed to it.

But the third party developer forgot to qualify the argument of `third_party_function()` with `const` qualifier.

So now the dilemma I am facing is whether or not to qualify the argument of `our_function()` with `const` thereby telling our users that we will not modify your strings.

I have two opposing arguments:

1. Argument in favour of `void our_function(const char *s)`: We want to tell our users that their strings are not going to be modified. So they are free to pass constant strings.
2. Argument against `void our_function(const char *s)`: If a future ugprade of third party code causes `third_party_function()` to modify the string it gets (say they uncomment the `s[1] = 'E'` statement), the user would have no clue at compile-time that their code may crash with segmentation fault at run-time. Any useful diagnostics they could have got at compile time are suppressed with the forced `(char *)` type cast which was a direct result of declaring the argument as `const char *`.

Which one of these two arguments (yay! pun!) is the technically correct argument?

Note: To keep this question objective and prevent it from being opinion-based, I am looking for technical arguments (not opinion) that leads to the conclusion that one option is better than the other. If from a technical standpoint none of the options are good, then that is the correct answer. If there is a better alternative, please tell me that in your answer.

Comment: Kick that lazy developer where it really hurts and either get a correct version of his lib or get your money back and use a different lib. (Yes, I have a dream ...)

Comment: @Olaf Kicking the third-party developer is something I don't have control over. I have control over only what I write in `our_function()`.

Comment: If you were to cast it, you should use `const_cast`, not a C style cast.

Comment: @RobK What's the advantage of using `const_cast`? Sorry, I haven't seen this kind of cast before. I tried Googling but I get only C++ results about it.

Comment: @RobK this is C not C++ tagged question

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at the tags.

Answer (score 4):

To be safe, copy the C-string you receive and use the copy to call the third party function and let your own function use the const qualifier (if it is its semantic).

Answer (score 0):

`const` is not the only way of creating a contract. If the library function has a contract that it does not mutate data, then that's fine, pass it whatever you want, casting away `const` as appopriate.

Jean-Baptiste Yunes' answer is good, but it's not about passing to a method that "forgot" to declare `const`, it's just about passing to *any* untrusted dependency. If it *did* declare `const`, it is, of course, still allowed to internally ignore that and do whatever it wants. Should you protect your client data anyway? Arguably, yes.

One plausible situation: The method first lowercases the string it receives. Then it does non-mutating operations on it. So it certainly cannot declare `const` even though the contract often guarantees it is not const. If *your* method only accepts, `const`, lowercase strings, you should feel free to use the library method, casting away `const`.

Comment: C does not support _methods_ anyway. And as OP does not have control over that library, it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Olaf libraries do indeed have "methods." I'm not sure your point beyond that -- that the OP should not be using the 3rd party in the first place

Comment: @Olaf C supports methods quite easily. A file encapsulates an object and its methods. A `struct data` type is defined in a file. A `static data obj` object is defined to keep the data private to the file. Then `static void f(struct data self, ...)` becomes private methods and `void g(struct data self, ...)` becomes public methods. This is a very common way of building libraries that need to maintain state in objects.

Comment: @djechlin: This is semantics, but not part of the C standard, nor is this supported by language constructs. A method is bound to an object (in the OOP sense) or a class. None is obviously true for C.

Comment: @LoneLearner: That is not what the term _method_ commonly implies. These are still seperate entities at the language level. And without further knowledge, we don't know about the semantics. Until then we should assume there are just _functions_, not _methods_.

Comment: @Olaf okay...  I changed the word "method" to "function" in my answer. Problem solved?